# zsh: command not found: truffle

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I have install: npm install -g truffle

Node version: v10.20.1

NPM version: 6.14.4
After installing npm install -g truffle, it gets install successfully, but when I checked

truffle version

it shows me ,command not found truffle

Comment: What's your O/S?

Comment: Mac OS catalina

Comment: Type `echo $PATH` and post the result

Comment: akshay@Akshays-MacBook-Pro solc % truffle version
zsh: command not found: truffle
akshay@Akshays-MacBook-Pro solc % echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/go/bin /Library/Apple/usr/bin /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
akshay@Akshays-MacBook-Pro solc %

Answer (score 1):

Try running `truffle version` in the same console you did the `npm install -g truffle`
If it works on that terminal but not in new ones it means that the npm is not configured to be persistent across your sessions.

Here is an example of how to enable npm in other sessions.

https://gist.github.com/rcugut/c7abd2a425bb65da3c61d8341cd4b02d#addappend-the-following-lines-in-bashrc

Comment: Install truffle via `npm install -g truffle`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When I check the logs of npm install, I noticed these lines:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
```

If you also have this kind of an error, that might be the reason.

I applied this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and here is why: https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/

After giving access to node_modules, I installed truffle again (this time it took much longer btw)

it worked for me, I hope it helps.